# Replacing specific elements in list python

Tags: python-3.5

```
Dinner = ['Meat', 'Veg', 'Milk', 'Grains']
DinneronMonday = ['Meat', 'Veg', 'Milk', 'Grains']
DinneronTuesday = ['Meat', 'Veg', 'Milk', 'Grains']
DinneronWednesday = ['Meat', 'Veg', 'Milk', 'Grains']
DinneronThursday = ['Meat', 'Veg', 'Milk', 'Grains']
DinneronFriday = ['Meat', 'Veg', 'Milk', 'Grains']
DinneronSaturday = ['Meat', 'Veg', 'Milk', 'Grains']
DinneronSunday = ['Meat', 'Veg', 'Milk', 'Grains']
```

I need help with overwrting elements in list, i know how to overwrite them however i don't know how to overwrite them using user input for example for dinner on monday i want to change all of the categories

Comment: So pretty much what i did, i want to do that with the user input

Comment: I'd recommend structuring this code a bit more by using a datatype that represents a meal. Then you can do operations on this datatype more conveniently.

Comment: @shuttle87 what do u mean

Comment: Maybe a dictionary with keys as the days of the weeks and values as lists of food.

Comment: @Let'sgothebeastboy Specifically I'd make a class that represents a meal then do operations on that and I would implement `__str__` for that class to aid in printing it. Another possibility would be a dictionary if you don't need so much structure.

Comment: @shuttle87 i have to use list cuz this assignment is about list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the python input method to set the options for each day. For example:

```
monday0 = input("Enter option 1 for Monday: ")
DinneronMonday[0] = monday0

// Add input for each
```

You could also store the input in some other collection structure and set the days options accordingly.  That's an assignment for the user ;)

Edit:

You could read the values into a list assuming your input is comma separated

```
// Input should look like - Steak,Chicken,Fish,Tacos  
options = input("Enter options for Monday: ")
DinneronMonday = list(options.split(','))

// Do the same for each day
```

Comment: Michael Gary i have to do 4 inputs for each day

Comment: @Let'sgothebeastboy, make a function that does this then pass the day as a parameter.

Comment: @shuttle87 i don't know how to do that pls help me

Comment: @MichaelGary how do  store the input in other collection structure u are talking about

Comment: I would recommend making my above answer into a method that you call pass in the day as a parameter a @shuttle87 mentioned earlier.

Comment: @Let'sgothebeastboy : I guess I am not understanding the assignment.  What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want, but I read your question as though you want to get input from user that you set as every element in one of your menu lists. If so, something like this might help:

```
    newItem = input("New menu item: ")
    DinneronMonday = [newItem for oldItem in DinneronMonday]
```

Comment: Forgot that raw_input is called input in Python 3. Edited answer.